# Testing characters not getting printed when testing a program in pycharm

Tags: python, testing, pycharm

I'm studying python with the "Python Crash Course" book.

Now I have reached chapter 11 "Testing your code", and I have a question.
The author has left the following note in the book:

*When a test case is running, Python prints one character for each unit test as it is
completed. A passing test prints a dot, a test that results in an error prints an E, and
a test that results in a failed assertion prints an F. This is why you’ll see a different
number of dots and characters on the first line of output when you run your test cases.
If a test case takes a long time to run because it contains many unit tests, you can
watch these results to get a sense of how many tests are passing.*

I use Pycharm, and when I test something Pycharm does not prompt the dots that the author was talking about.

**I'd appreciate it if you could help me out with my problem**

I'll also leave the code I'm running here, because I thought it might help

````
from survey import AnonymousSurvey


class TestAnonymousSurvey(unittest.TestCase):
    """Tests for the class AnonymousSurvey."""

    def setUp(self):
        """
        Create a survey and a set of responses for use in all test methods
        """
        question = "What language did you first learn?"
        self.my_survey = AnonymousSurvey(question)
        self.responses = ['Arabic', 'Farsi', "English"]

    def test_store_single_response(self):
        """Test that a single response gets stored correctly."""
        self.my_survey.store_response(self.responses[0])
        self.assertIn(self.responses[0], self.my_survey.responses)

    def test_store_three_responses(self):
        """Test that a set of three responses is stored correctly."""
        for response in self.responses:
            self.my_survey.store_response(response)
        for response in self.responses:
            self.assertIn(response, self.my_survey.responses)```

**Thanks!**
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default test runner that `unittest` uses, [`TextTestRunner`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TextTestRunner), prints its progress output to `stderr` by default and is thus not captured by PyCharm.